# R showed an error message when create a variable in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I wrote my program in Tinn-R. When I ran it in R by using source(), an error message showed. The following example only includes partial loop.

```
          for (nn in 1:length(nSim))  ##whether the right loop???
              {
              r.all <- c()
              p.final <- array(0, c(15,5))  #1-5 a, b1, b2, b3, b4; 6 group id
              r.reference <- cbind(GRM_sim(t(p.sample[,1]), t(p.sample[,2:5]),sample.all[iS],0,rep(1,sample.all[iS]))

            DIF_ID <-c()
            DIF_index <- rep(0,15)
            for (iC in 1:length(CDIF))
            {
              if (CDIF[iC]==1)
              {
                DIF_ID <- sample(1:15,DIF.all[iDIF.all])   ##consistent DIF 
              }
               for (id in 1:length(DIF_ID))
               {
                  DIF_index[DIF_ID[id]] <-1
               }
              ...
```

Error in source("120413consistentMH.R") : 
  120413consistentMH.R:107:17: unexpected symbol
106:
107:                 DIF_ID

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is typical for a missing paren. Get yourself an editor that matches parens or learn to make more liberal use of spaces and carriage returns. The fifth line that scrolls off the end of this webpage is missing a closing paren:

```
r.reference <- cbind(GRM_sim( t( p.sample[,1]  ), 
                              t( p.sample[,2:5]), 
                               sample.all[iS],0, 
                              rep(1, sample.all[iS])
                               )
                      ^
            missing paren here
```